# Logging a java background process

Tags: java, shell, spring-boot, logging

I've created a spring boot java application that uses slf4j as frontend and log4j as backend.

I've a script called `start.sh` that executes the following command:

`java -jar myapp.jar > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 & PID=$!`

This command redirect `stdout` and `stderr` into $LOG_FILE (called console-output.log). The problem is that I don't know if I should keep this redirect to file or use the `logging.file` property from application.yaml (i.e. create log file using the log4j framework) because in my logs folder I have 2 files that are identically: one called `console-out.log` and one called `myapp.log`

The java process is a background process meaning that you start it and then you leave it do it's job.

What would be the best practice here?

Comment: I think you should be using application.yaml, as it is flexible to change the logging level etc and provide message format and much more

Comment: But will log4j catch stderr logs and System.out.println things?

Comment: Yes, it will , you have to just set the System.setOut and System.setErr from your main class

Comment: Is this a good practice?

Comment: As far as I think you should start the java application in background using nohup command so you don't have to keep the terminal open and should use application.yaml or log4j.xml to output to FileAppender so that logs keep writing down in a file.